# TextView in custom adapter (ListView) gravity right not working for one line text

Tags: android, listview, textview, gravity

So I have custom adapter listView. There I have TextView. And I want to show it from right (gravity.right)

But when I am setting attribute Gravity.Right (I also tried change it dynamically) But it is not working for single line text and working for multiple line text. Like in this picture

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Acer"
    android:textColor="@color/"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    app:fontFamily="@font/" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/"
    app:fontFamily="casual" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of"
    android:textColor="" />
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show your layout ? Is the width of your TextView set to `match_parent` ?

Comment: @Bruno - check now

Comment: Strange, the layout seems good. Are you sure there is no modification on code side ? Are you sure the text doesn't have any remaining space characters for example ? Try to replace `right` by `end` maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/"
        app:fontFamily="casual" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/" />

</LinearLayout>
```